# How to list only files of a certain type in terminal?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

How I can list all files of a certain type in a directory?

For example, if I want to see all MP3 files in the current folder, what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregarding *suffix*, you can use the `file` command to identify audio files.  That is more complicated than an simple `ls` command can do, so one would use a script.  For example (ID3 seems to be `file` jargon for MP3):

```
#!/bin/sh
for name in "$@"
do
    case $(file "$name") in
    (*Audio*ID3*)
        ls -l "$name"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Putting *that* in your executable path (such as `~/bin` as "ls-audio") you could then do

```
ls-audio *
```

to list details of just the MP3 audio files.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` - is that really `sh` and not `bash`? - if you mean bash, then change to bash.

Comment: If I wanted to use a bash-specific feature, I would use bash.  This script does not rely upon any bash-specific features (just POSIX).

Comment: It seems I might have not stated it clearly enough. Hint: is `sh` on OSX just a hard link to `bash`? For Ubuntu 14.04 it is a link to `dash`... you might have problems arising from the fact that you're not getting what you expect - POSIX or not, the degree of compliance varies.

Comment: It's a symbolic link (not a hard link).  However, your point is obscure, since I tested with dash on Debian before posting my answer.  If you have some *specific* criticism of the script's use of POSIX features, that would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using OS X spotlight:

```
mdfind -onlyin /path/to/directory  "kMDItemKind == 'MP3 audio'"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply go to the directory that you wish to query by using the `cd` command to get to the directory you want to query. Than type in `ls *.mp3` to list all files with the extension of the file you wish to find.

For example if you want to see all `.txt` files on your desktop you can simple type `cd ~/Desktop` and next type in `ls *.txt` which will give you the result of

```
lists.txt
output.txt
output2.txt
```

Comment: That lists files whose suffix is ".mp3" (it's possible to have mp3 files without the suffix).